# Rundeck first setup and MariaDB not working

Tags: mariadb, rundeck

I'm setting up Rundeck CE 4.8 on a Windows 2019. I've implemented all requirements but the DB seems to be a stopper. I've installed MariaDB and I'm following the Rundeck documentation to set it up. I've created a db called rundeck, a user called rundeckuser successfully, grant it permissions and in HeidiSQL I see that the user is assigned those permissions on db. When I start rundeck the service goes up but page is not reachable, port 4440 is not up on the server. I have a question:

The Rundeck documentation mentions setting up the schema in the DB, but does not say how. In fact my db is empty, no tables. So, as the first run was done with the embedded H2 db, shall I now perform a migration from H2 to MariaDB (same as in MySQL I guess)? I mean, is it this the way to perform the schema update? I have the impression that somewhere the user is not able to write to the db, but I don't know how to check that.

Here below my rundeck-config.properties file:

```
#loglevel.default is the default log level for jobs: ERROR,WARN,INFO,VERBOSE,DEBUG
loglevel.default=INFO
rdeck.base=E:/rundeck

#rss.enabled if set to true enables RSS feeds that are public (non-authenticated)
rss.enabled=false
server.address=0.0.0.0
server.port=4440
dataSource.dbCreate = update
grails.serverURL=http://<fqdn>:4440
dataSource.driverClassName = org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
dataSource.url = jdbc:mysql://mysql.rundeck.local/rundeck?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
dataSource.username = rundeckuser
dataSource.password = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStart=true
# Pre Auth mode settings
rundeck.security.authorization.preauthenticated.enabled=false
rundeck.security.authorization.preauthenticated.attributeName=REMOTE_USER_GROUPS
rundeck.security.authorization.preauthenticated.delimiter=,
# Header from which to obtain user name
rundeck.security.authorization.preauthenticated.userNameHeader=X-Forwarded-Uuid
# Header from which to obtain list of roles
rundeck.security.authorization.preauthenticated.userRolesHeader=X-Forwarded-Roles
# Redirect to upstream logout url
rundeck.security.authorization.preauthenticated.redirectLogout=false
rundeck.security.authorization.preauthenticated.redirectUrl=/oauth2/sign_in

rundeck.feature.repository.enabled=true
```

In the service log I see:

```
[2022-12-19T14:28:35,867] INFO  liquibase.lockservice - Successfully acquired change log lock

[2022-12-19T14:28:39,461] INFO  liquibase.changelog - Reading from rundeck.DATABASECHANGELOG

Running Changeset: core/ConstraintsIndexesKeys.groovy::3.4.0-56::rundeckuser (generated)

[2022-12-19T14:28:40,133] INFO  liquibase.lockservice - Successfully released change log lock

[2022-12-19T14:28:40,180] ERROR boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed

liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set core/ConstraintsIndexesKeys.groovy::3.4.0-56::rundeckuser (generated):
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: (conn=18) Can't create table `rundeck`.`scheduled_execution_filter` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update") [Failed SQL: (1005) ALTER TABLE rundeck.scheduled_execution_filter ADD CONSTRAINT FK22545y15qs4iqod1ljyqsm1fi FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES rundeck.rduser (id)]
```

However, I'm not performing any update/migration. I don't know why it is showing that in the log. I have thought that it could be due to the line:

```
dataSource.dbCreate = update
```

so I've changed it to:

```
dataSource.dbCreate = none
```

but restarting the service provides the same error.

Comment: silly silly me... forgot to amend the:   dataSource.url = jdbc:mysql://mysql.rundeck.local/rundeck?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false  with the my server. Fixed, and schema has been applied. However Rundeck page still unavailable. App won't load...

Comment: Do you see any clue in the service.log? the grails.serverURL parameters is well defined with the correct external URL?

Comment: Thanks @MegaDrive68k, I'm adding the content of the log to the post...

Comment: Try commenting or omitting this line `dataSource.dbCreate` (at `rundeck-config.properties` file) and re-launch the Rundeck service.

Comment: Commented the line, restarted: same errors...

Comment: to me it's a bug.. I'm filing a report...

Answer (score 0):

I've deleted and recreated the db twice to same result. Now I've created a db with different name and it went through. No errors. The app still does not come up but it's a different story now. I'm guessing I must have played with the original db too much when trying to fix things.